# Find equal values in array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, object

```
    equal_points = {18:[
    {'scored_goals':500,'lost_goals': 520,'team':'team A'},
    {'scored_goals':490,'lost_goals': 530,'team':'team B'},
    {'scored_goals':500,'lost_goals': 510,'team':'team C'},
    {'scored_goals':490,'lost_goals': 500,'team':'team D'}
    ]};
var tmp_scored = [];
angular.forEach(equal_points, function(item) {
        angular.forEach(item, function(team) {
            tmp_scored.push(team.scored_goals);
            console.log(tmp_scored);
        });
});
```

Hi,I would like sort object by scored but if they are equal then sort them by lost goals.How can I check which objects have the same values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `sort` function of the Array to implement your sorting by `scored_goals` and also by `lost_goals` like:

```
var arr = [
  {'scored_goals':500,'lost_goals': 520,'team':'team A'},
  {'scored_goals':490,'lost_goals': 530,'team':'team B'},
  {'scored_goals':500,'lost_goals': 510,'team':'team C'},
  {'scored_goals':490,'lost_goals': 500,'team':'team D'}
];

arr.sort(function (a,b) {
  return a.scored_goals>b.scored_goals && (a.lost_goals>b.lost_goals );
});
```

You can read more about it here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort